# Can I declare a member function of the outer class to be the friend function of in an inner class

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have a class manage the content of a file and convert the file to a binary buffer, and I have a inner class which is a element in the file(basically it represents a single line). Like:

```
class CSR{
private:
    //some fields
public:
    Elem operator[](int numRow);
    //other methods
public:
    class Elem{
        private:
            //other fields
        public:
            friend CSR::Elem CSR::operator[]( int r );
    };
};
```

The compiler(VS 2012 Express) tells that "CSR has no member operator[]"

Comment: Can you please indicate the line number the compiler complains about? Also, what is `SVDFeatureCSR`?

Comment: @arne the line that I declare the friend function. And I have changed the SVDFeatureCSR to CSR for simplisity

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the language rule is, but forward declaring Elem seems to make both gcc 4.7 and VS 2010 happy:

```
class CSR{
private:
    //some fields
public:
    class Elem;
    Elem operator[](int numRow);
    //other methods
public:
    class Elem{
        private:
            //other fields
        public:
            friend CSR::Elem CSR::operator[]( int r );
    };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a forward declaration of your inner class - but unfotunately that is not allowed.
[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600385/c-nested-class-forward-declaration-issue) has some possible work arounds - none particularly attractive.