# C++: Declare member functors for later definition

Tags: c++, member, functor

I have some functors that I want to make member variables of a class, which I declare in my header file like so

```
class A {
public:
//...
typedef struct functor1 functor1;
//...
}
```

I then want to define these functors in my source file (purely for organisational reasons), something like

```
A::functor1 {
     void operator()(int in) const {
     //stuff
     }
};
```

However this gives me an 'unqualified-id before ‘{’ token' error. Can anyone show me how to achieve what I'm aiming for or something similar?

Comment: You can't create variables with just  a declaration.

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2600679/4342498) what you are looking for?

Comment: Funnily enough I was actually trying to get away from hiding the functors in a private namespace. I've settled on just leaving them in there and writing some accessors