# Forward declare a inner class type, is it possible?

Tags: c++, templates

Ok here is the situation.

```
//foo.h
struct A1{ 
 struct A2{};
};

//bar.h
#include "MyString.h"
class A2; //note, not including foo.h
TEMPLATE_INSTIANTIATE_MAP_OF_TYPE(String,A2*); //assume compiler doesn't do this
```

Is it possible to make the above situation work? I try to create a `MyMap<String,A1::A2*> m;` but the compilers throws undefined reference errors. Is it possible to make the above work without having bar.h import foo.h?

Comment: What happens when you just try to `class A1;class A1::A2;`? (I don't have a compiler handy.)

Comment: @MichaelWilson, that fails unfortunately, see here http://codepad.org/v2BBKR3G

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I forward declare an inner class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1021793/how-do-i-forward-declare-an-inner-class)

Answer (score 2):

Sadly, it isn't. Nested classes can only be declared inside a class definition.

Comment: So even though A1::A2 has the same name as A2, I cannot create a `Map<U,A1::A2*>`  even though a template instantiation has been done for `Map<U,A2>` ?

Comment: @user814628: Indeed; `A1::A2` and `::A2` are separate names. You'll need a declaration of `A1::A2` to use it as a template argument, and that declaration can only be inside the definition of `A1`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to declare nested classes outside a class definition.
class Logic is the outer class. LogicImp is the forward declared struct.

```
class Logic
{
public:

    Logic();
    ~Logic();

private:
    struct LogicImp;
    std::unique_ptr<LogicImp> limp_;
};

struct Logic::LogicImp
{
    int nLogical_;
};

Logic::Logic():limp_(new LogicImp())
{
}

Logic::~Logic()
{
}
```