# How to access a struct from another another C++ class?

Tags: c++, qt, struct, forward-declaration

Hello I have a struct in a TreeItem class:

```
// TreeItem.h
class TreeItem
{
public:

  struct TreePair
  {
    QString   sa_key;
    QVariant  sa_value;
  };

  //... blabla
}
```

I would like access that struct TreePair from another class TreeModel , which has class TreeItem already formarded in its header:

```
// TreeModel.h
class TreeItem;
class TreeModel : public QAbstractItemModel
{
    Q_OBJECT
    //..
}

// TreeModel.cpp
TreeModel::TreeModel(const QStringList &headers, const QString &data, QObject *parent)
  : QAbstractItemModel(parent)
{
  QVector<TreePair> rootData; // TreePair was not declared in this scope
}
```

My strcut was not declared in this scope?? In every class it was already automatically set like

```
#ifndef _TREEITEM_H
#define _TREEITEM_H
#endif
```

Comment: `TreeItem::TreePair` note that `TreeItem` must be defined before `TreeModel` in that case. Why not make `TreePair` a separate definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `TreePair` is nested inside `TreeItem`, it needs to be

```
QVector<TreeItem::TreePair> rootData;
```

Comment: Error: incomplete type 'TreeItem' used in nested name specifier
   QVector<TreeItem::TreePair> rootData;

Comment: @MarkZltr you must include `TreeItem.h` within  `TreeModel.cpp`

Comment: @MarkZltr forward declaration won't work see [the answer to this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1021793/how-do-i-forward-declare-an-inner-class)