# How forward declare class that is within a class?

Tags: class, declaration, forward

I have a class I will call Outer declared in a header Outer.h. There is a class declared inside Outer that I will call Inner.

In another header file class declaration I would like to declare

```
Outer::Inner *myInner;
```

I would like to forward declare Outer and Inner rather than including "Outer.h" and potentially getting into "header file loop hell." I have tried various combinations of

```
class Outer;
class Inner;
class Outer::Inner;
```

to no avail. Is it possible to do what I am trying to do, or must I move Inner out of Outer or some similar approach?

MSVS  2010 if it matters, but I need to end up with portable code.

Comment: I believe you will have to define the inner-class in the outer-class.

Comment: @Rodolfo, not sure what you mean in terms of actual code. Inner *is* *declared* inside of Outer. Is there a syntax to forward declare Inner inside of Outer? I guess that is the question I am asking.

Comment: I mean you can do: `class Outer { public: class Inner; };` in your `Outer.h` file.

Comment: I am missing something. I do what you suggest in Outer.h. It all works fine, except for the problem in my post. How do I forward declare Outer and Inner in *another* class declaration header file?

Comment: I just tried adding class Outer {public: class Inner; }; to the header in question but that results in a "complete" (but highly erroneous) declaration of Outer, not a *forwarad* declaration.

Comment: Completely misinterpreted your question... Sorry.

Comment: Sorry. Duplicate. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1021793/how-do-i-forward-declare-an-inner-class Short answer: no can do.