# Why can't a class have a pointer to an instance of another class without forward declaration?

Tags: c++, typename

I know it's impossible to do

```
class foo{
    foo bar;
};
```

Because the compiler wouldn't know how much memory to prepare for `foo`.
But consider:

```
class A{
    B::C* foo;
};

class B{
    class C{
    };
};
```

It seems quite reasonable that the compiler would know exactly the size of A no matter the definition of the C. Why isn't this possible then? (Does the standard forbids that explicitly? for what?)

---

I got a very crude way by-pass the constraint that is to treat `foo` as a `uintptr_t`, then `reinterpret_cast` it back to `C`, this is just to show that I really don't get the (objective) reason, and I know it's a really really bad practice if used without decent reason.

---

*Finally it turns out to be forbidden by the standard.*

Comment: This isn't specific to pointers or anything. You can't use names until they appear in general, barring members of the same class.

Comment: @chris, isn't just saying it's a pointer enough for consideration on size?

Comment: @YiFei `other` might not be a type name, it could be a variable's name, and so on.

Comment: Then it would be tricky. How can other be a variable name when presented as in the place of a type name?

Comment: Wait until you take a class on compiler design and implementation and study [LALR(1) parsers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LALR_parser). Then, come back here and ask this question again.

Comment: @YiFei So compiler error should be generated. Compiler need to check if you make such mistakes.

Comment: @YiFei, C++ is full of context-dependent parsing. Consider [this example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b52895ed4cf86c45). In the first function, `B* A` is a multiplication. In the second function, the very same line is a variable declaration.

Comment: @songyuanyao I got your point, as you expect compiler would have to check all its ambiguous meaning, but I was expecting that compiler should check for its correct meaning (once possible) then because one of its ambiguous absolutely don't work (as variable name), it then switch to treat it as a type name

Comment: @chris, good example, but as in my comment to songyuanyao, if in the first struct of your example, you don't have a member field named B, I hope that the compiler would just pass on and assume it's a type name.

Comment: @YiFei The compiler is not entitled to make such an assumption.

Comment: @EJP, Yep, good to hear, but is it enforced by standard?

Comment: In a template , all sorts of names are allowed without declaring them first, if they are scope-qualified with a template parameter. Ambiguity over whether such a name is a type is resolved with the `typename` keyword.   It's not part of the language, but what OP seems to want could be achieved by allowing `typename` to do the same thing outside of a template.

Comment: @Spencer Wow, cheers, you got it exactly, pity is that it's not part of language

Comment: @YiFei Thus a comment. Besides, I'm not sure adding that capability would achieve anything.

Comment: @Spencer Just for better OOP *experience*, since we don't then have to compromise to compilers (since I don't find standard forbids it) to declare nested class, see also [Jared Par's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1021809/5215536)

Answer (score 1):

One big challenge is following:

```
class other {};

namespace N {
  class foo {
    other* p;
  };

  class other {};
}
```

Which `other*` should be considered? Too much of work for compiler. Though we can be explicit by `::other` or `N::other`, it still creates confusion in above case.

Comment: Upvote! Agree that too much work for compiler (isn't it already much now?) :D; but see `Name lookup shall find an unambiguous declaration for the name` in the standard, which in my case is not involved. I would expect it will use the formerly declared should have priority, i.e. If declared, use declared, else pending for later check, if reach EOF, raise error then.

Comment: @YiFei, thanks. Actually currently the above example code works fine & there is no ambiguity error. However, with your suggestion, that code may break. Moreover, whatever feature you are asking for, is already available using `template`s.

Comment: Great hint! I'm to use explicitly instantiated templates in source file thanks

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: That is because the standard dicates the syntax to be so. Unfortunately it's as simple as that.

This is the path I followed:

1. You open standard e.g. [c++11 draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf).
2. You seek section about classes it's section 9. You immediatietly see it has subsection "9.2 Class members". There is whole syntax defined. After some reading you get to `member-declarator`. The most important part in our context is `declarator`.
3. Section 8. Declarators. In p4. you have the syntax for `declarator`. After going through all the formal definition of the fancy syntaxes supported you will notice that it hinges on `id-expression`.
4. This is defined in 5.1.1 Primary Expressions. General (`[expr.prim.general]`). And it has to be a `qualified-id` of `unqualified-id`.

So your question could be rephrased to "Why does the namelookup not work like that?" But that is another question.

FWIW, not much I guess, but it's a design decision. It would need to keep track of all failed resolutions for the compilation unit. Doing lazy check in this context comes with quite far reaching implications.

Comment: What do you mean by "You see that the declarator is not there."?

Comment: The definition for `declarator`. I should probably rephrase it.

Answer (score 0):

After the example

```
class foo{
    other* bar;
    ...
};
class other{
    ...
}
```

… which (1) uses an undeclared name, and (2) lacks a crucial semicolon, you ask

> **”** Why isn't this possible then? (Does the standard forbids that explicitly? for what?)

The Holy Standard requires that every name must be declared before it's used.

Note that in a given C++ implementation, even data pointers can be of different sizes (`void*` is guaranteed to be able to hold any data pointer), not to mention function pointers.

An alternative to declare-before-first-use requirement could be to adopt a default, like with implicit `int` in the early C days. E.g. the compiler could assume that `other` was a class type. But that would not be very helpful in general, and it would complicate the language.

However, in this particular case it's possible to combine the necessary minimum declaration of `other` with its first use:

```
class foo{
    class other* bar;
    //...
};

class other{
    //...
};
```

Alternatively you could use an ordinary forward declaration:

```
class other;

class foo{
    other* bar;
    //...
};

class other{
    //...
};
```

Just so the compiler knows that `other` is a class type, and not e.g. a function, or a synonym for `char` or `void` (pointers to these types are the largest, if there is any variability in the size of basic raw data pointers).

---

You then assert:

> *”* The dummy example I posted above may seem have no real meaning. The reason why I want to do without forward declaration is that when you got a nested class, there's no forward declaration that can preserve the encapsulation.

That's wrong.

E.g. this works nicely:

```
class Foo
{
private:
    class Other;
    Other* bar;

    class Other{};

public:
    Foo(): bar( new Other ) {}
};
```

However, the shortcut with declaration in the first use, `class Other* bar;`, doesn't work in this case. That's because it effectively would declare `Other` as a namespace level class instead of a nested one.

Comment: Not to wrangle, but the standards only says "A declaration (Clause 7) may introduce one or more names into a translation unit or redeclare names introduced by previous declarations." It don't say we can't use name before declaration (I know I'm definitely wrong but don't know why or we don't need forward declarations any more), so where specifically in the standard states that. Thanks.

Comment: @YiFei: You get that as a consequence of scope rules and name lookup. If a name hasn't been declared, name lookup fails. The standard requires that name lookup shall succeed.

Comment: @YiFei I'm using the draft for 11 linked in my answer but I'm quite sure this didn't change. The definition for `id-qualifier` says: "*An identifier is an `id-expression` provided it has been suitably declared (Clause 7).*" and it probably isn't declared till it actually is.

Comment: @luk32, thanks, I found that statement, I do think they should add a "before".

Comment: @YiFei I think "*has been*" implies it. They would probably add "*or is declared at later point of the program*" in the other case.

Comment: @luks32 Alright, I got it at 3.4.1-7-(7.1) (Unqualified name lookup), which explicitly stated that. What a pity. (I'm on 14 working draft)

Comment: Consider [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/951234/forward-declaration-of-nested-types-classes-in-c), from a OOP perspective, I don't really wanna break it to a un-nested class, thanks