# Trouble with forward declaration: incomplete type 'enums::Category' used in nested name specifier

Tags: c++, c++11, enums, c++14, crtp

I want to have a wrapper around enum which will give me chance to convert it to string and vice-versa.

Base class is the following:

```
template<typename TEnum>
class StringConvertedEnum {
public:
    static std::string toString(TEnum e);

    static TEnum toEnum(std::string &str);

protected:
    static const std::map<std::string, TEnum> _stringMapping;
    static const std::map<TEnum, std::string> _enumMapping;
};
```

And then I want to have something like this:

```
class Category : public StringConvertedEnum<Category::Enum> {
public:
     enum Enum {
          Category1,
          Category2,
          OTHER
     };
};
```

However at the current moment it's not compile via this error:

```
incomplete type 'enums::Category' used in nested name specifier
```

How to fix this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I forward declare an inner class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1021793/how-do-i-forward-declare-an-inner-class)

Comment: @YSC: I think it's a relevant read, but not exactly a duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `Enum` is declared inside your class, it doesn't exist before its declaration when you're specifying that `Category` inherits `StringConvertedEnum`. That is an incomplete type, see relevant part of the standard ["3.3.2 Point of declaration [basic.scope.pdecl]"](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.scope.pdecl) (thanks AndyG for pointing this out in the comments).

The easiest way to solve the problem is to declare `Enum` outside `Category`:

```
enum Enum {
    Category1,
    Category2,
    OTHER
};

class Category : public StringConvertedEnum<Enum> {};
```

This follows [Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/), even if we're speaking about C++:

> Flat is better than nested.

The second easiest way is to declare a base class:

```
class BaseCategory {
public:
    enum Enum {
        Category1,
        Category2,
        OTHER
    };
};
class Category : public BaseCategory, public StringConvertedEnum<BaseCategory::Enum> {};
```

As also pointed in the comments, you should consider [scoped enums](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum#Scoped_enumerations) if you're using modern C++.

Comment: +1. the enum was an incomplete type. Relevant standard: "3.3.2 Point of declaration [basic.scope.pdecl]" Also, OP should use a scoped enum, being that they are using C++11

Comment: @AndyG Thx added that to the answer

Comment: Thanks, however I'm not sure I got how scoped enums could help to solve this problem. Would be nice if you clarify it in your answer.

Comment: @silent_coder scoped enums can't help to solve this problem. That's just a safer way to declare enums