# Compiler error while pushing a pointer to a forward declared type into a typedef'd vector

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, reference

So the error I'm getting is:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'std::vector<Type*>::push_back(AnimationAutoComplete::Type*&)'
 neighbours.push_back(samplePoint);
                                 ^
```

I made a striped down version project to reproduce the error.
This is my `AnimationAutoComplete.h`

```
#include <vector>

class Type;
typedef std::vector<Type *> SetOfConstTQ;

class AnimationAutoComplete {
public:
  AnimationAutoComplete() {}
  ~AnimationAutoComplete() {}

  SetOfConstTQ getNeighbours();

  class Type
  {
  public:
      Type() {}
      const double point = 3.0;
  };
};
```

And my `main.cpp`

```
#include "AnimationAutoComplete.h"

SetOfConstTQ AnimationAutoComplete::getNeighbours()
{
    SetOfConstTQ neighbours;

    Type *samplePoint = new Type();

    neighbours.push_back(samplePoint);

    return neighbours;
}

int main()
{
    AnimationAutoComplete main;
}
```

Comment: `::Type` is not `::Whatever::Type`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You [cannot forward declare a nested class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1021793/5470596).

Define `Type` outside of `AnimationAutoComplete` and you'll fix your program:

```
#include <vector>

class Type;
typedef std::vector<Type *> SetOfConstTQ;

class AnimationAutoComplete { ... };

class Type { ... };
...
```

Alternatively, `typedef SetOfConstTQ` after `AnimationAutoComplete::Type` is fully defined:

```
#include <vector>

struct AnimationAutoComplete {
    struct Type {};
    typedef std::vector<Type*> SetOfConstTQ;
    SetOfConstTQ getNeighbours();
};

AnimationAutoComplete::SetOfConstTQ AnimationAutoComplete::getNeighbours()
{
    SetOfConstTQ neighbours;
    neighbours.push_back(new AnimationAutoComplete::Type());
    return neighbours;
}

int main()
{
    AnimationAutoComplete main;
    (void) main.getNeighbours();
}
```

[live on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a1c41918e1fb85ec)

Comment: You should mention that moving the declaration *inside* the outer class is also a valid solution.

Comment: @MaximilianKöstler I just did that ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can not forward declare it this way.
`AnimationAutoComplete::Type` is not the same as `Type`.

Answer (score 1):

As said, you can not forward declare the nested class.

But if you want your class nested hen you can typedef it in class and use later like:

```
class AnimationAutoComplete {
public:
  AnimationAutoComplete() {}
  ~AnimationAutoComplete() {}

  class Type
  {
  public:
      Type() {}
      const double point = 3.0;
  };

  typedef std::vector<Type *> SetOfConstTQ; // Typedef here
  SetOfConstTQ getNeighbours(); // use it after typedef
};

AnimationAutoComplete::SetOfConstTQ AnimationAutoComplete::getNeighbours() // return type will come under scope of AnimationAutoComplete
{
    SetOfConstTQ neighbours;

    Type *samplePoint = new Type();

    neighbours.push_back(samplePoint);

    return neighbours;
}
```