# How can i manage a set of derived class enums without needing to instantiate the derived class?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, gcc, crtp

I'm trying to understand why the following code snippet will not compile:

```
template <class Derived> struct Base {
    const std::set<typename Derived::Foo> types() const { return theSet; }
    std::set<typename Derived::Foo> theSet;
};

struct Derived : Base<Derived> {
    enum Foo { X,Y,Z };
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) { Derived x; return 0; }
```

I get an error saying that the the line with `types() const` is an invalid use of incomplete `struct Derived` - but all it needs to know is that the type of the set is a `Foo` enum so I'm not sure I understand the error or if there's a way around it that doesn't require me to make that set of type `int`..

The full error from the compiler says:

```
error: invalid use of imcomplete type 'struct Derived'
    const std::set<typename Derived::Foo> types() const {
error: forward declaration of 'struct Derived'
struct Derived : Base<Derived>
```

Comment: Always helpful to include the actual error message in your post

Comment: I suppose that when compiler tries to instantiate Derived class it sees that it is derived from Base<Derived> and instatiates it. But at this moment Derived isn't fully instantiated so compiler doesn't know what the type Derived::Foo is (the std::set can't be instantiated with incomplete template parameter).

Comment: @DmitryGordon is there a simple way around this? I fear I might have to make the set be of ints...

Comment: @CaptainObvlious added it

Comment: Don't use the same name for a template parameter and an external type.  Are you sure you're showing us the whole code?

Comment: @Palace Chan I see only one solution - make the enum template parameter, same as Yatima suggests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To compile this example compiler will need a forward declaration for nested type which does not seems to be possible (see [How do I forward declare an inner class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1021793/how-do-i-forward-declare-an-inner-class)) so simplest workaround might be to make `Base` class to take two templates and move `Foo` out of your class definition:

```
#include <set>

template <class T, typename F> struct Base
{
    const std::set<F> types() const { return theSet; }
    std::set<F> theSet;
};

enum class Foo { X,Y,Z };

struct Derived : Base<Derived, Foo>
{
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Derived x; return 0;
}
```