# Problem about Initializing inner class Instance

Tags: c++, constructor

```
class ListNode;

class LinkedList {

private:

    ListNode* start;

    class ListNode {
    private:
        int data;
        ListNode* next;

    public:
        ListNode() : data(-1), next(NULL) {}
        ListNode(int data, ListNode* next=NULL) : data(data), next(next) {}

    };


public:
    LinkedList() : start(NULL) {}
    LinkedList(int data) : start(new ListNode(data)) {}
};
```

there is a error in `LinkedList(int data) : start(new ListNode(data)) {}`.
It says "you cannot innitialize LinkedList* value using LinkedList::ListNode construction".
Whats is the exact problem means and solutions???

Comment: Better: [c++ - How do I forward declare an inner class? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1021793/how-do-i-forward-declare-an-inner-class)

Comment: Simplest fix would be to move `ListNode* start;` after `class ListNode { ... };` (and delete the forward declaration `class ListNode;` which is simply wrong).

Answer (score 2):

The forward declaration of `class ListNode;` is not the same thing as class `LinkedList::ListNode` defined later.

When the compiler finds `ListNode* start;`, `LinkedList::ListNode` is unknown,  so the compiler uses the `ListNode` forward declaration. By the time the compiler gets to `start(new ListNode(data))`, `LinkedList::ListNode` is known and has a closer scope so it is used instead of `ListNode`.

Result: `start`, a `ListNode *` is pointed at a `LinkedList::ListNode`. The types clash and the compiler rejects the code.

The simplest solution is to remove the forward declaration of ListNode, since it's likely just an attempt a to fix an earlier undeclared identifier error and will never be defined, and move `ListNode* start;` to after the definition of `LinkedList::ListNode` so that there is no ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot forward declare an inner class outside the containing class. So, try declaring it first, and then declaring a pointer to it:

```
class LinkedList {

private:
    class ListNode {
    private:
        int data;
        ListNode* next;

    public:
        ListNode() : data(-1), next(NULL) {}
        ListNode(int data, ListNode* next=NULL) : data(data), next(next) {}

    };

    ListNode* start;

public:
    LinkedList() : start(NULL) {}
    LinkedList(int data) : start(new ListNode(data)) {}
};
```

Comment: Hmm... more exactly you cannot forward declare an inner class *outside* the containing class. But you can do it *inside* the containing class.

Comment: I'll edit it to be clearer for future visitors.